# How to use isset() in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm looking for the conversion from the PHP code to Delphi. Currently, i'm stuck when handling with the Isset() function in PHP code. Are there any way i can convert the below code into Delphi ?

```
$collection = array(
'doc1' =>'php powerbuilder',
'doc2' =>'php visual'); 
$dictionary = array();
$docCount = array();    
foreach ($collection as $docID => $doc) {
        $doc = strtolower($doc);
        $terms = explode(' ', $doc);
        $docCount[$docID] = count($terms);
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if (!isset($dictionary[$term])) {
                $dictionary[$term] = array('df' => 0, 'postings' => array());
            }

            if (!isset($dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID])) {
                $dictionary[$term]['df']++;
                $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID] = array('tf' => 0);
            }
            $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID]['tf']++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do i need to combine the array of records to implement that ?

Comment: Looks like you need to use a dictionary

Comment: Please post the Delphi version you're using so we know if you have generics or not. Maybe someone will find the time to write some code, but I doubt anyone will venture without knowing if generics are available or not.

Comment: I'm using Delphi 2007 Enterprise Edition. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet? Because if not it looks like you want us to translate your code for you and that's generally frowned upon here.

Comment: I believe there are many ways you can organize code to achieve this. I'd use a special class designed to do this. But, one of your array  seems to have only one key, or the code is incomplete $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID]['tf']++ ... it appears to me it would be better if it is just $dictionary[$term]['postings'][$docID]++ .. unless of course there is something more than 'tf' it could count.

Comment: seems to me, that you should use `array_key_exists` instead of `isset`. Delphi equivalent for `isset` is `assigned()`. in your case, task is to check if array/dictionary has specified key. so, in Delphi it depends on your implementation of all of these structures;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP arrays are, according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), a one-size-fits-all data structure that works as an ordered list or as a hash map (dictionary). Delphi does not have a similar built in data structure, you can only get either vector (ordered list) behavior, or hash map / dictionary behavior. And the dictionary behavior is only easily accessible on Delphi 2009+ because that's the version that introduced Generics.

The easy to use data structure that's available on Delphi 2007 and can be used for `inset` type of operations is the `TStringList`, in it's `Sorted := True` mode. But this is no true dictionary, it's just a sorted list of strings where each string can have a value associated with it. You would use it like this:

```
procedure Test;
var L: TStringList;
begin
  L := TStringList.Create;
  try
    L.Sorted := True; // make the list "Sorted" so lookups are fairly fast
    L.AddObject('doc1', SomeData); // SomeData can't be string, it needs to be TObject descendant
    L.AddObject('doc2', SomeOtherData);
    if L.IndexOf('doc3') = -1 then // this is equivalnt to the `inset` test
    begin
      // doc3 is not in list, do something with it.
    end;
  finally L.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This of course is not a complete answer, but should get you started.

Comment: `TStringList` does not have an `Add()` method that takes 2 parameters.  You need to use `L.Add('doc1=' + SomeData)` or `L.Values['doc1'] := SomeData` instead, and then use `L.IndexOfName()`.